# Cookie Cutting/Clip with Nodes - Remove everything outside Clip

Tags: geometry-nodes

Trying to do something in nodes which I think should be quite simple.
[image]

Im trying to remove (cut/clip) all elements outside the larger circle using nodes etc.
Tried a number of different ways of using Mesh Boolean without any luck.  Results range from a blank screen to a large solid circle in the middle !!

Here is the basis of Geo Node. Note : Mesh Boolean (TRC) leftover from testing
[image]

Any pointers

Thanks
LeeB
Blender 3.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I assume you want to intersect the circles, and possibly keep them as curves, I suggest the following solution:

[image]

The trick here is that I set the resolution of the circles to be instantiated very high at the beginning, then compare the positions of the points with the given radius, and filter them out.

By setting the circle to non-cyclic beforehand, and rotating the open position outwards, I get an arc that is open to the outside.

---

Another, more mathematical solution could look like this:

[image]

The trick here is that I pre-calculate the start angle and sweep angle of an arc.

Since you have the following information:

- $a$ = radius of the outer circle
- $b$ = position of the circle centers or radius of the instantiation
- $c$ = radius of the small circles

From this you get the formula:

$\alpha = acos(\frac{b^2+c^2-a^2}{2bc})$

With this formula, it is easy to determine the angles for the arc, which means that the individual instances only need to be correctly aligned along the points:

[image]

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.2+)*</sub>

Comment: Thanks .... works great ... love your work :)

Comment: @LeeBerry Thanks a lot too, you're welcome!